# ActiveRecord: trigger action to only already saved objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `Movie` model with many `Photo`. Only one Photo can be set as `default?` at the same time for a given Movie.

I'm wondering how to implement this on Rails. I added a the following code,

```
before_save :check_if_default

def check_if_default
  self.movie.photos.where(default: true).update_all(default: false) if self.default?
end
```

But by looking into the console it is not updating new objects to true state. When try to do so they remain as false.

```
> a.photos.find(600).default = true
> a.photos.find(600).save
=> true 
a.photos.find(600).default
=> false
```

I'm wondering If this is maybe because I'm iterating all objects including the present which is not currently saved and set it as false?

If this is the case, how could I iterate only those items that are already saved on the database? I guess using `after_save` callbacks here would not be recommended given I should make sure I set other possible `default?` to false before setting it to true for a new photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not persisting back the entity that you updated.

try:

```
b = a.photos.find(600)
b.default = true
b.save
```

or

```
a.photos.find(600).update_attributes! {default:true}
```

or